# Moderator vote to close on the first posts queue not recognised as an action

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I voted to close a question from the First Posts review queue.

The question was put on hold but the "I'm Done" button wasn't enabled:

[image]

Refreshing the page just showed:

> This post isn't reviewable

(or words to that effect) and the "Next" button.

I didn't notice whether my review count incremented or not, but the action doesn't seem to have been registered on the [history tab](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history):

[image]

I don't get to see many posts on the SO review queues so I want my review to count, dammit!

Comment: I've also seen this in the Low Quality queue when converting an answer to a comment.

Comment: Confirmed. @Michael: that's kind of a special case, I suspect the dialog doesn't realize that the answer is being deleted. Or did it work at one time?

Comment: I haven't been a moderator long enough to know if it ever worked. What I do know is, that as a mod, the queue does provide the `mod` link to click on and perform those operations.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that the moderator close vote triggers a state change (open -> on hold) of the question, causing a refresh that also refreshed the I'm done button after it was already enabled.

After closing the question as a moderator the `I'm done` button is now enabled and clicking it should record your review, increasing your review count.

However, refreshing the page would still cause the `This post isn't reviewable` message to appear.

Fix rolled out to sites in build 2013.7.18.861